# Using listField to display Json string

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am retrieving a string of values from json url. I have done it like...

```
for(int i=0;i<totalList;i++){
  String strAlert=jsArrShpList.get(i).toString();
  JSONObject joAlert=new JSONObject(strAlert);
  String shoppingList = joAlert.get("CategoryName").toString();
```

}

Now i want to add the strings to a list field and i want to get selected index. So plz help me out on how to do it and some sample code will be really helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get selected index you can use the method `getSelectedIndex()` from the `ListField`.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393950/blackberry-add-items-to-a-listfield) for an example on how to add new items on the ListField.

See an introductory tutorial about list fields [here](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=898).