# How to display a large text area

Tags: blackberry

I'd like to display a large text area which uses most the blackberry screen area. What is the best GUI component for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think LabelField whould be enough, check this:

```
    String text = "";
    for (int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
        text += "word" + i + " ";
    }

    LabelField largeLabel = new LabelField(text, LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);

    add(largeLabel);
```

Answer (score 1):

[BlackBerry - Add items to a ListField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393950/blackberry-add-items-to-a-listfield)